# Wordpress Login if user_meta (confirmFlag = 1)

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I created an extra user meta field `(confirmFlag = 0)` when new user register on my page.

They get a email to confirm their registration. They click on the link and on the page the user meta field turns into `1 (confirmFlag = 1)`.
Now, the thing is, how can I make user only login if the user meta field is `1 (confirmFlag = 1)`.

If ths field is `1` everything is ok and the user gets to the dashboard.
If the field is still `0` the login should fail and a message should say that the user have to confirm the registration by the link in the email.
Any suggestion?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo(); //wordpress global variable to fetch logged in user info
    $userID = $current_user->ID; //logged in user's ID
    $havemeta = get_user_meta($userID,'test',true); //stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'test'.

if ($havemeta) 
{ 
echo 'your stuff';
 }

else {
        echo "No";
    }
```

or Try this plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-meta/

Comment: Hello, so it seams I dont need to use any action hooks like wp_login? Where do I put this code? Into my functions page?

Comment: Thanks for the plugin, i will use it!